# Getting started with converted STL to DXF

Tags: 3d-models, stl

I converted the STL file through an online converter https://www.cadforum.cz/catalog_en/stl2dwg.asp

(I work in the program autocad 2017)
Now I open the resulting DXF and I don’t know how to work with it. How do I merge polygons into a whole model?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? STL is a model defined by its surfaces and ca be properly converted to AutoCAD if done right. https://www.laserscanning-europe.com/en/laserscanning-forum/english-laser-scanning-forum/laserscanning-software/import-stl-autocad Or you use the right plugin: https://www.cadforum.cz/forum_en/forum_posts.asp?TID=6024&title=how-to-open-stl-file-from-autocad

Comment: I do not know how to convert the resulting model into the body. For this reason, I can not do anything with the model in the autocad. I usually created my own models, and it was easy, but for the first time I was faced with converting and editing STL.

Comment: What is your end goal? To bring an existing STL into Autocad to edit it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. Need to go: Network -> conversion to surface

Then we get a surface that is already easy to work with.

Comment: I edit the STL and dxf with Sketchup, the STL to change any 3D surface and DXF to convert 2D to 3D printables.